# How should you express a negative binomial distribution in an exponential family form?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, exponential-family

When $X$ is $X_1$,...$X_n$, how do you express the following negative binomial distribution  in an exponential family form?

$$
f(k;r,p)\equiv\text{Pr}(X=k)=\binom{k+r-1}{k}(1-p)^{r}p^k~~~~~\text{for}~k=0,1,2,\ldots
$$

Comment: Hey, I think you should be more specific as to what it is that you're doing and what your problem is.  Your question, as it currently stands, probably won't get a very good or satisfying answer, and probably will get a number of downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new and don't know how to write an equation in LaTex. I just know how to use it for a very simple notation. I don't know how specific the question needs to be. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question *is*, @Python_R. Can you say more about what you want to know?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Warning:** The negative binomial distribution has several alternative formulations for which the formulas below change.

A distribution $f(x;\theta)$ belongs to an exponential family if it can be represented in the form:

$$
f(x;\theta)=h(x)\exp\left[\eta(\theta)T(x)-A(\theta)\right]
$$
The value $\eta$ is called the canonical (natural) parameter of the family, $T(x)$ is a [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficiency_%28statistics%29) for $p$, $A(\theta)$ is called the log-partition function (it's a normalization factor and sometimes called *log-normalizer* or *cumulant generating function*), and $h(x)$ is an arbitrary function called *base measure* or *carrier measure* which is 1 in many cases (e.g. exponential distribution, gamma distribution, Bernoulli distribution, ...). If the negative binomial distribution **with known parameter $r$** (if $r$ is unknown, the negative binomial family is *not* an exponential family) has the following distribution:

$$
f(k;r,p)=\binom{k+r-1}{k}(1-p)^{r}p^k~~~~~\text{for}~k=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
Then it can be rewritten in exponential form as:

$$
\begin{align}
    f(k;r,p) &=\binom{k+r-1}{k}\exp\left[\ln(p^{k}(1-p)^{r})\right] \\
             &=\binom{k+r-1}{k}\exp\left[k\ln(p) + r\ln(1-p)\right] \\
\end{align}
$$
So the parameter $\theta$ of the distribution is $p$ (i.e. $\theta=p$) and the natural parameter is $\eta=\ln(p)$, the sufficient statistic for $p$ is $T(k)=k$ (i.e. $T(k)=\sum X_{i}$, the sample sum), the log-partition function is $A(\eta)=-r\ln(1-p)$ and $h(k)=\binom{k+r-1}{k}$. See for example the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) for a nice overview of the theory and many common distributions. Nice references can also be found [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~andrzeje/lmml/exp-family-glms.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4863.pdf).

Comment: +1.  Also, $h(x)$ is called the *carrier measure* because in the measure-theoretic formulation of exponential families (e.g. Shao's book), it is an actual measure.

Comment: @NeilG Thanks Neil, I didn't know that. Do you mean Jun Shao's book  [Mathematical statistics](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Springer-Texts/dp/0387953825/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1372054523&sr=8-1&keywords=jun+shao+mathematical)? If yes, could you point out where in the book? Thanks very much.

Comment: @COOLSerdash:  Yes, that's the one.  I don't have the book with me, but I remember seeing the measure theoretic formulation there.  Just doing a quick Google search, you can find a reference to "carrier measure" in "The Geometry of Exponential Families" by Bradley Efron

Comment: The carrier measure can usually be made into a standard carrier measure (by rescaling the sample space) for a continuous distribution, but is rarely equal to one for a discrete distribution.